# facebook like box duplicates faces.. or not

Tags: iframe, facebook-likebox

I tried to read everything I could in order not to disturb, but the behavior of the facebook like box plugin is wired.

I must begin with the fact that everything in my facebook page (https://www.facebook.com/pages/tennisitgr/428483287200942) is shown correctly.

When i try to produce the code for the like box plugin from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ :

- if I am not logged in to facebook i can see only the stream, the
  header, and the number of people who liked my page but there are NO
  faces (the show faces option is checked..).
- if I am logged in to facebook I can see faces but all the faces shown
  are duplicate (except mine).

Maybe I have a setting wrong in my page (I checked the permissions..) because when I try to generate the plugin for another page it is shown correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Nikos.